# Combining DCF and P/B

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, value-investing

If you have two companies with the same value according to DCF, but they differ in their equity. Let's assume company A has 1M USD in equity while company B has 0M USD equity. This means that company A should be better to buy than company B. But why is this not generally discussed when talking about DCF? Shouldn't this be an obvious component when valuing a business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it's *not* obvious that company A is better. DCF looks at the *future* cash flows of the company, and does not consider the current equity at all. It typically forecasts several years of cash flows and then treats the company as a *perpetuity* into the future at some constant growth rate or a *terminal value* (often using multiples that take equity into account) to end the cash flow stream. So if the DCF values are the same, then either  B has more cash flow and makes up the 1M in cash flows (accounted for in the terminal value), or the companies are treated as perpetuities and the additional equity now becomes irrelevant (e.g. after 20 years company A is worth 1.001 billion and company B is worth 1.000 billion).

That said, it's not *wrong* to think that the company with more existing equity is "better" when comparing DCF results, since DCF is forward-looking and has some degree of uncertainty, but it's not a universal truth that should be considered in all circumstances.

Comment: So my confusing was due to the fact I was missing the terminal value component or considering the fact that the equity part can become irrelevant. Thanks, that answer was exactly what I was looking for!